# Text being displayed twice in IE10

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-10

I am developing an application in AngularJS with a drop-down present.
As the default value of drop-down, I set it to "Select a Purpose".
It appears fine in Chrome, Firefox and other IE browsers.

In IE10 only, it displays 2 strings, i.e., "Select a PurposeSelect a Purpose".

Has anyone faced this issue earlier?
Can someone provide me some pointers as to why this is happening or how this can be resolved?

Here is my code snippet:

```
<select id="purpose_combo" ng-model="selectedFile.data.purpose" class="form-control"
            ng-disabled="selectedFile.purposeChoice == 'primary' || !selectedFile">
      <option selected hidden value="" translate>Select a Purpose</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in purposeList" value="{{item}}"
              ng-selected="item == selectedFile.data.purpose">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: why you need the "select" on default option and "ng-selected" on extra options? Could you try to remove? Probably, angular ng-model will select by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ng-options:

```
<select id="purpose_combo" ng-model="selectedFile.data.purpose" class="form-control"
        ng-disabled="selectedFile.purposeChoice == 'primary' || !selectedFile"
        ng-options="item for item in purposeList">
  <option value="">Select a Purpose</option>
</select>
```